# Is it possible and how to manage multiple release variants (i.e. customized apps) with git-flow?

Tags: git, release, git-flow

For reasons long to describe (i.e. related to highly customized applications), I need to keep in parallel different variants of the same release for a product (i.e. .

I haven't found any reference of such a requirement related to git-flow,
so my question is:
does git-flow include any hint/suggestion/procedure to managed this scenarios?
Or should I just manage them outside the facilities provided by git-flow?

P.S. I know I could use other mechanism, such as *[feature flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle)* to deal with customized versions, but unfortunately this would require a lot more effort right now.

Answer (score 0):

The [git-flow workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) describes a `release` branch as a temporary branch to "support preparation of a new production release".
The final target for a release is the `master` branch, infact closing a `release` in git-flow will merge it to `master` and `develop` and (optionally) delete the `release` branch.

In your case you probably need to keep a separate, non temporary `custom release` branch in parallel to `master`.
Based on the git-flow description, this scenario is not included in the standard git-flow workflow and tools, thus you need to use standard git commands to achieve that result.